# How to recall getItem(int position) in fragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-viewpager

How to remove fragments in a viewpager? I want to call the code again. Right now it's not calling the code again when the user takes the re-test in the quiz app.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new QuestionPagerFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("que", pageData[position]);
        b.putInt("pos", position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageData.length;
    }

}
```

Comment: Although your question is not very clear, after your adapter is created you generally add and remove Fragments from a PagerAdapter by overriding the PagerAdapter.getItemPosition(Object) method.  To notify the ViewPager that changes have been made, call PagerAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer of the question, We have to simply use FragmentStatePagerAdapter as it destroys the fragment if it is done and FragmentPagerAdapter will stores the fragments in the bundle and it will restores the fragment from the bundle when its recalled.Hope it helps!!